# "Try and get some rest" OR "Try to get some rest"?

Tags: infinitives, speech, compounds

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

> Try **and** get some rest
>   (or)
>   Try **to** get some rest

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct, and synonymous. The "try and" version is fairly colloquial, however.

Incidentally, the "try and" version doesn't have inflected forms: we don't say *"tries and gets", for example.